# Substitutions next to angle brackets in Sphinx

Tags: python, versioning, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use [substitutions](http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#substitutions) in a [parsed literal block](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal-block) in my [Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/) like this:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <version>|release|</version>
</dependency>
```

Which gets rendered like this:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <version>|release|</version>
</dependency>
```

Where what I want is this:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

If I add spaces around the substitution in the source, I get this:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <version> 1.7.3 </version>
</dependency>
```

So I know `release` is defined as I expect. How can I get rid of the spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
.. parsed-literal::

   <version>\ |release|\ </version>

.. |release| replace:: 1.7.3
```

Reference: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism