# Sphinx variable substitution in code blocks

Tags: python, variables, block, python-sphinx, substitution

Using Sphinx 1.2.3 and given this RST snippet:

```
.. code-block:: xml

    <foo>
        <bar>|version|</bar>
    </foo>
```

and in `conf.py` I have:

```
version = '1.0.2'
```

How do you ensure that the above RST snippet renders as:

```
<foo>
    <bar>1.0.2</bar>
</foo>
```

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821511/substitutions-in-sphinx-code-blocks) indicates that we should use `.. parsed-literal::` instead of `.. code-block::`, but that does not work, nor does the referenced link in that question work either.

I also want to retain syntax highlighting.

Comment: Here is how you can get the substitution working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25557867/407651. But it is not possible to also retain syntax highlighting (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27185467/407651).

Comment: @mzjn thanks for the comment - if you want to provide a normal answer, I'll award it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the wanted output by using [backslash-escaped whitespace](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#escaping-mechanism):

```
.. parsed-literal::

  <foo>
       <bar>\ |release|\ </bar>
  </foo>
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to also retain syntax highlighting (you can get that with the `code-block` directive of course, but then the substitution won't work).